# Firebase RTDB: How to filter child events based on a nested field?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

Given that every entry in my Firebase Realtime Database has a `version` field that represents the timestamp it was last edited, how can I filter them by their version such that only child events that are newer than X are delivered?

```
val listener = object : ChildEventListener {
    // Not relevant
}

val ref = database.getReference("exercises").child("userId")
ref.addChildEventListener(listener)

// TODO: ref.filter(version>localVersion)
```

*For context as to why Im looking to do this. There are very many entries, and while Id like to know whenever any of them change, observing all of them at all times results in too big of a memory footprint (>150 mb).*

Json representation of a data model (exercise):

```
{
  "details" : {
    "category" : "LIFT",
    "equipment" : "CABLE_MACHINE",
    "muscles" : [ "BACK" ],
    "name" : "Row in Cable Machine",
    "status" : "AVAILABLE"
  },
  "id" : "1",
  "source" : "CUSTOM",
  "version" : 1648446264560 // This is the field Id like to filter on.
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data). Please also indicate the exact data you want to filter.

Comment: @AlexMamo Ive edited it into my question. Thanks for taking a look, let me know if theres anything more I can provide!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- How can I filter them by their version such that only child events that are newer than X are delivered?

Since your `version` filed is a number, to get only the objects newer than a particular value you can use the [Query#startAt()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query#startAt(double)) function, which:

> Creates a query constrained to only return child nodes with a value greater than or equal to the given value, using the given orderBy directive or priority as default.

Or [Query#startAfter()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query#startAfter(double)) function that:

> Creates a query constrained to only return child nodes with a value greater than the given value, using the given orderBy directive or priority as default.

Comment: Thank you Alex, how would I go about actually using that in my sample though (considering that version is a child field)? My reference points to a list of exercises, ideally Id like to observe the entire list - but filtering it such that only entries that have a version which starts after X is delivered.

Comment: I did find ref.orderByChild("version").startAfter(X); I believe that does exactly what I want! Ill play around with it today to see if it works in practice too!

Comment: Yes, sounds good. Give it a try and keep me posted.

Comment: It does exactly what I want - thanks for bringing it to my attention! :)

Comment: When using these methods Ive noticed that they have zero impact on memory consumption (even though the result-set contains 2 items instead of 2000). Is this intentional, or did I stumble upon a bug?

Comment: Without seeing the code that produces that, it's hard to say. So please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.